# Any suggestions on having master-master replications around the world by nosql solutions?

Tags: nosql

I would like to set up databases that are put at different data centres around the world. For this, I think some nosql solutions may suit the case. For example, couchdb, maybe. Eventual consistency is ok for this.

The case does not limit to document based solution. But I would like to know the possibility, potential problems for setting up master-master replications around the world as I see the cases the servers are in same data centre most likely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two NoSQL DBs that come to mind when mentioning cross datacenter replication *("master-master replications around the world")* are:

- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/)

Both of them seem to have fairly decent cross datacenter replication abilities, so which you should go with should be decided upon in a different manner.

If you want a KV-Store (where you can simply look up binary blobs using keys), then you ought to go with Couchbase.

If you want something similar to the SQL concept of rows and tables and whatnot (albeit, without relational functionality such as `JOIN`), then Cassandra and CQL might suit you better.